# "Open Changes and Comments in Visual Studio" does not work in the new Outlook

Tags: outlook, new-outlook

Outlook recently asked me if I want to try the new look. It asked me too many times and finally I gave up. Then it somehow stopped showing me the option to go back to my previous design.
Anyway - in the new outlook, somehow the parser doesn't render as a link the "Open Changes and Comments in Visual Studio" which is essential part of my daily job to work with code reviews in the Visual Studio. I remember there was some security concern with the previous version which made me do some changes (don't remember if those changes were in the registry). Those changes though were to prevern the old Outlook to constantly ask me if I should proceed with opening the Visual studio. It wasn't abount not rendering the link as the new does.
Any ideas?
Any ideas how to swicth back to my good old Outlook?

Cannot figure out what to do for both problems.

Answer (score 1):

Now you have both old and new Outlook applications installed on the system.  You can even run them concurrently :)

But if running outlook.exe actually runs `New Outlook` for you then you need:

- Uninstall Outlook

or

- Run `Regedit.exe` and go to the following hive (or the same with 15.0, if you don't have 16.0):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences
```

There you should find the `UseNewOutlook` key which you need to set to `0`  which means that running old Outlook actually runs it. Viola!